# Ionic ngmodel with an list and the id in key

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a problem.

I want to link a toggle button with the following and list and use the id of this toggle like a key.

```js
//Here my fonction to convert 
 transform(d)
   {
  
    alert(d); //when i put this.id here i have undefined value
    return Number(d);
   }
```

```html
<ion-toggle id="0" name="toggle1" [(ngModel)]="listToggle1[this.id)]"></ion-toggle>

<!--Here the pb is the "id" is a string and for the list i need a key valu in int -->

<!--This work but it's not dynamic -->
<ion-toggle id="0" name="toggle1" [(ngModel)]="listToggle1[0]"></ion-toggle>

<!-- i try this -->

<ion-toggle id="0" name="toggle1" [(ngModel)]="listToggle1[transform(this.id)]" ></ion-toggle>

<!--i call a function with the id in parameter, and this typescript function will convert the string id in an int value

But the pb is here in transform(this.id) the this.id is undefined-->
<!--This work but again not dynamic -->
<ion-toggle id="0" name="toggle1" [(ngModel)]="listToggle1[transform('0')]" ></ion-toggle>
```

I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Is id a variable defined in Component? or did you want to use the id of the html element? Because the way you wrote it, id should be a variable defined in the component

Comment: no id it the id of the toggle it self and y have alredy try (ionChange)="notify2(this.id)" and this work it send the good id a the function notify2

Comment: Please always describe the expected and the actual (problematic) behaviour in debug-like questions. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using: (ionChange) and then detect which element was clicked in component, like this:

HTML:

```
<ion-toggle id="0" name="toggle1" (ionChange)="listToggle1($event)"></ion-toggle>
```

and TS:

```
listToggle1(event) {
    console.log(event._elementRef.nativeElement.id);
}
```

This prints the id of your toggled element, then do with it what you want.

Comment: in my case listToggle1 is an variable listToggle1:any=[]  define in the component and initilized with 2 value true and false

Comment: in the end i want to dubliquate this toggle and other element and the value of this duplicate element will be listToggle1[id] so the 1st will be the key 0 the second key 1 .....

Answer (score 0):

In the end like i said i want to clone/dublicate some html element

My project I have a sort of alarm than the user can configurate (timer text notifcation....)

I have a "template" and normaly sould be able to dublicate this in order to creat multiple alarm with different pameter

[myapp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYel9.png)

so normaly when the user click on "add new" the same html element than "the form" is add but whith new value.
That is the idea. But I don't have a good clone function

```js
 duplicate(d) {
 alert(d);
 var i = 0;
 var original = document.getElementById(d);

    var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone

 clone.id = Number(d)+1;
 alert(clone.id);
 

    original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);

}
```

The only thing that i can modify is the id of the new element (i cant modifie other like the ngmodel) also when i clone and element i can't modifie the new element in the html page (in the point of view of the user)

Peraphs some know a good way to clone/dublicate html element?